# Is this Adobe Postscript?

Tags: pdf, adobe, postscript

I am doing a massive set of file conversions and several of them happen to be ".dat" files. When I open them I see that the first line is "%!PS-Adobe". Here's an example.....

```
%!PS-Adobe
^M%c$in
^M/c$in {72.0 mul} def
^M%DEFINE MARGINS
^M/C$LMAR .2    c$in def            %LEFT MARGIN
^M/C$RMAR 8.4   c$in def            %RIGHT MARGIN
^M/C$TMAR 10.8  c$in def            %TOP MARGIN
^M/C$BMAR .2    c$in def            %BOTTOM MARGIN
^M/C$CF /Courier def        %saves /Courier as C$CF
```

etc...

Am I correct in assuming that these are indeed Adobe Postscript files and ** NOT ** PDFs?
How hard is it to convert these to PDF? I was thinking command line perl via ImageMagick or something but right now I'm a little stumped about what's been handed to me.

Thank you SO Much...
Janie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert these to PDF using Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device, or for simplicity the ps2pdf script supplied with Ghostscript.

Comment: BAM! Answered my question! Thanks KenS (and everyone else). The S.O. community constantly makes my life easier. JW

Answer (score 1):

Yup, that's Postscript.  A PDF would start with "%PDF".   If the text "^M" is literally there like that, then it was created on a Mac and got screwed up being copied to or edited on other platforms. (Maybe it was when the sample was pasted into the S.O. edit box?)  It defines some variables with dollar signs in their names, which makes it look funny.

Answer (score 1):

`%!PS-Adobe` is the signature for conforming Postscript files. (Non-conforming Postscript can get by with `%!`.) The signature for PDF files is `%PDF-`.

Comment: Conformance refers to document structuring conventions. Not strictly relevant for straight conversions (which require interpretation (wherein the structure comments are ignored)).